# Static ip on different subnet cannot reach unpopular websites

Tags: linux, networking, dns, subnet, static-ip

I have a printer, raspberry pi, and a regular router

```
// printer
static ip: 10.0.0.100
subnetmask: 255.255.255.0
default gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

```
// raspberry pi /etc/dhcpcd.conf
static ip_address: 10.0.0.10/24
static routers=192.168.1.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
```

```
// router
ip: 192.168.1.1
subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
```

I set my raspberry pi to ip `10.0.0.10` so that it could communicate with the printer. This works as expected. However, internet access is limited. The pi can only reach "popular" websites like facebook, youtube or yahoo. I don't need it to reach all websites, just heroku.com which doesn't work. Why is this happening and how do I make heroku reachable?

Some potentially helpful outputs from the pi

```
// ip r
default via 192.168.1.1 devwlan0 src 10.0.0.10 metric 303
10.0.0.0/24 wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.10 metric 303
192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 scope link src 10.0.0.10 metric 303
```

```
// ifconfig
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 10.0.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.0.255
inet6 2601:182:cf00:68d0::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x0<global>
inet6 2601:182:cf00:68d0:c5c4:5dc2:223d:23dd prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x0<
```

I also tried changing the pi to use `static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8` but that didn't work either. `nslookup` works for heroku, but curl and the browser don't.

```
// nslookup heroku.com
Server: 2001:558:feed::1
Address: 2001:558:feed::1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: heroku.com
Address: 50.19.85.154
Name: heroku.com
Address: 50.19.75.132
Name: heroku.com
Address: 50.19.85.156
```

```
// /etc/resolv.conf (i didn't edit this file)
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 2001:558:feed::1
nameserver 2001:558:feed::2
```

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you're accessing those websites via IPv6, whereas your IPv4 configuration is actually completely broken.

(Compare `ping -4 www.google.com` and `ping -6 www.google.com`. Many websites nowadays have an IPv6 address alongside the usual IPv4, and it usually has nothing to do with their popularity; often even small sites are behind CloudFlare which supports IPv6 for all its CDN nodes.)

Regarding your IPv4 network: It isn't *technically impossible* to have an out-of-subnet gateway (at least Linux-based systems will cope with this), but it's highly unusual, and to make this work properly, **the gateway itself** must know that `10.0.0.0/24` is on-link on the *LAN* interface. Currently, if the gateway doesn't know that, it is unable to deliver any responses from the WAN back to your printer or the Pi.

There are three ways to fix this:

- Create a static route on the router for 10.0.0.0/24 as destination, with only the LAN interface in place of the route's gateway.

  This will allow the router to send responses to 10.0.0.x, and therefore will allow the printer and all other 10.0.0.x devices to have Internet access.
- Assign the router's LAN interface addresses from both subnets. This is the option if you want both 192.168.1.0/24 and 10.0.0.0/24 to be functionally equal.

  On some routers this feature is called "secondary IP" or "virtual IP" (not to be confused with "virtual server"). Some routers don't offer it as an option at all.

  This ultimately achieves the same thing as the previous "static route" option – but is somewhat preferred because it more accurately defines what's going on in the network.
- Assign the Raspberry Pi's `wlan0` interface addresses from both subnets. This is the option if you need the Pi to have access to the printer, but *don't* want the printer to have access to Internet.

  On regular Linux you can just `ip addr add` both addresses to the same wlan0 interface, or have two `interface wlan0 inet static` sections in /etc/network/interfaces.

  This lets the Pi to choose the most appropriate address for outgoing packets.

Comment: To add to this, dhcpd.conf at least USED to be the configuration file for a DHCP server, and dhcpcd.conf the client. Considering that, and how this looks to have been configured, I think the OP used a guide for setting up a raspi as a router to get to this state.

Comment: @djsmiley2k interesting. I was actually following the guide here. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address.

What do you mean `dhcpd.conf used to be the config file for a DHCP server`? I'm actually trying to follow @grawity 's suggestion, but I'm trying to understand the relationship between `/etc/dhcpd.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces`. To add to @grawity's suggestion, would it be possible to  setup a static ip + dyanmic ip combo? That way the static ip is just for the printer while the dynamic ip is for the internet.

Comment: @Simon: I think the point is that you're confusing `dhcpd.conf` and `dhcpcd.conf`. Your provided example was titled with the former, but clearly showed content from the latter.

Comment: @grawity sorry about the carelessness. definitely meant `dhcpcd.conf`. will edit.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried a few different settings. Still don't fully understand the relationship between `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, `/etc/network/interfaces`, and files in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/<some custom file of any name>` so I can't explain why it works. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I know it's related to NetworkManager and the update from Jessie -> Stretch. But a detailed flow of what happens between these files and the network would be helpful.

I tried putting values in `/etc/network/interfaces` but any value I put, whether multiple entries or even single entries, I'd lose internet completely.

It wasn't until i created a file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan` with the contents

```
auth0 wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.10
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

That I was able to access all websites and my printer. Even more strange is that the that the `ifconfig` output when using `dhcpcd.conf` vs using `/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan` is *identical*.